# How to zoom UIScrollview together with added UIImage

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a background image that is added to UIScrollView with zoom enabled. I am trying to add additional UIImage's on top of the background image that zoom together with the background image?

The idea is to have a background with multiple playing cards were the user can either see the whole playing field with small playing cards or zoom in the whole background including the playing cards for better views on the playing cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UIScrollview` should contain a single zoomable `UIView` subview. That subview should contain your background `UIImageView` and all of the card `UIImageView`s as it's own subviews (if you add the background image first, it will be layered at the back of the resulting composite view)

The containing `UIView` that is the immediate subview of your scrollview should be the return value to the UIScrollviewDelegate method

```
  - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

You can manage your view hierarchy through a `UIView`'s `subviews` property, which is an `NSArray` of views. They are layered in the order of the array, so the first view on the array will be at the back when the views are composited for display.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use the scrollviewdidzoom delegate method to notify you when the scroll view has been zoomed in and out.

From there you could do a number of things like present new UIImages at a specific zoom level using the scrollView.zoomScale property.

Let me know if this helps.